# How to Convert JSON object to plain comma separate string in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

```
var $json = [{name:'abaneel',age:23},
    {name: 'john', age: 32},
    {name: 'Dev' , age:22}
];
```

How to create this type of string from this json object in php as like this string:

```
$simple string ="abaneel,23,john,32,Dev,22";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here what you need to do:

```
$json = '[
  {"name": "abaneel", "age" : 23},
  {"name": "john", "age" : 32},
  {"name": "Dev", "age" : 22}
]';
$implode = array();
$multiple = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($multiple as $single)
    $implode[] = implode(', ', $single);

echo implode(', ', $implode);   //this will output abaneel, 23, john, 32, Dev, 22
/*
    You can see that it will be hard to distinguish that where line(one array is ending);
*/
echo implode(' | ', $implode);  //will output abaneel, 23 | john, 32 | Dev, 22
```

hope this will help

Comment: i am newby in stack overflow i cant understand  what do u mean by mark as answer .... but its work nice . thank you so much

Comment: I mean you should accept this as answer, if you hover the answer, under the vote button there will be a tick mark, check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json ='[
  {"name": "abaneel", "age" : 23},
  {"name": "john", "age" : 32},
  {"name": "Dev", "age" : 22}
]';

$data=json_decode($json,true);
$your_string="";

foreach($data as $key=>$v){ 
    $your_string.=$data[$key]['name'].",".$data[$key]['age'].",";
}
$your_string= trim($your_string, ",");
echo $your_string;

 ?>
```